# Display array after action

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a little app that downloads some names from the web, and then appends them to an array.

```
func fetchTitle(identifier: String, completion: (title: String) -> Void) {
        let profileUrl = NSURL(string:"http://www.facebook.com/" + identifier)!
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(profileUrl) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let urlContent = data {
                let webContent = NSString(data: urlContent, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                let websiteArray = webContent!.componentsSeparatedByString("pageTitle\">")
                let secondArray = websiteArray[1].componentsSeparatedByString("</title>")
                let title = secondArray[0]
                completion(title: title)
                print(title)

            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }



    //print(newArray)


    var titles = [String]()
    //let identifiers = ["100001986741004","100003866283798","100003455181526"]
    let queue = dispatch_queue_create("titles", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

    dispatch_apply(newArray.count, queue) { index in
        let identifier = newArray[index]
        fetchTitle(identifier) { title in
            dispatch_async(queue) {
                titles.append(title)
                array.append(title)
            }
        }
    }
```

I know it's pretty complicated, because it takes numbers from an array and turns them into names downloaded from the web, but never mind about that. The problem is, when I print title, it gives me the names, so I assume it does append them to the array, but when I print the array, it gives me no result.. I think this is because it takes a little while to download the data from the web, and the print happens immediately, but how to I delay the print (or display into table view) until the download is complete?

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't know about swift, but when your data has been retrieved, in Objective-C you can call [tableView reloadData];  should be simple enough to translate to Swift

Comment: Thanks man! This is what I needed!

Comment: No prob, I put it as the answer to this question so feel free to accept it as the answer.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about swift, but when your data has been retrieved, in Objective-C you can call [tableView reloadData]; should be simple enough to translate to Swift

Comment: Well I tried this but I can't find the way to call it. Do I need to create an IBOutlet for it?

Comment: If you are using Interface Builder, create an IBOutlet for it and then refer to tableView as the name that you give your table.